# Can と and な have the same meaning?

Tags: particles, parsing

I was told that the following uses of と and な after 色々 were the same.

> 彼女のために色々と甘いものを買ってきた。I bought a bunch of sweets and brought them to my GF.
>   彼女のために色々な甘いものを買ってきた。

If this is true, is this an added use of the generic particle と that is not listed in this definition?

> と
>
> particle / conjunction :
>
> if;  when
>
> このシャンプーを買うと素敵なヘアブラシがついてきます。This shampoo comes with a nice hair brush.
>   彼女は、どうしてそんなことが可能なのかと尋ねている。She's asking how that's possible. ▾
>
> and
>
> １２と２４と７と１１の合計は５４です。The sum of 12, 24, 7 and 11 is 54.
>   いまやろうと思ったのに。I was just about to get started any-how. ▾
>
> with
>
> 私はあなたとお話してよかった。I have enjoyed talking to you.
>   彼女は今忙しいので、あなたとお話できません。She is busy at present and can't speak to you. ▾
>
> particle used for quoting (with speech, thoughts, etc.)
>
> 「美しい」とか「醜い」といった言葉は相対的な用語である。The words 'beautiful' and 'ugly' are relative terms.
>   そういう相手の前では、私の見せ掛けだけの怜悧な技術は、見抜かれた時に負けていたと思う。I think that against somebody like that, my seemingly clever techniques would be seen through and then I would be defeated. ▾

How does the と in the first quote work?

Answer (score 5):

No, the 「と」 and 「な」 do not have the same meaning or function.  「と」 enables an adverbial function and 「な」, an adjectival one.

In the sentence:

> [彼女]{かのじょ}のために[色々]{いろいろ}[と][甘]{あま}いものを[買]{か}ってきた。

「色々と」 modifies the verb 「買ってきた」.

But in the sentence:

> 彼女のために色々[な]甘いものを買ってきた。

「色々な」 modifies the noun 「（甘い）もの」.

Part of your confusion may have arisen from the fact that the first sentence is difficult to translate into natural English in such a way that it will show that 「色々と」 modifies 「買ってきた」.

The second sentence would translate swimmingly into English --- "bought and brought a variety of sweet things".

Answer (score 2):

According to a [dictionary](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%84%E3%82%8D%E3%81%84%E3%82%8D/), 色々(と) is an adverb, while 色々な is an adjective. It means this と is not considered a particle but a part of a word in the widely accepted grammar.

You can say, 彼女のために甘いものを色々と買ってきた, which shows 色々と works as an adverb.

Moreover, [this dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/154670/m0u/%E3%81%A8/) says that the particle と has 13 meanings/functions including a suffix to make an adverb.

Comment: That と is a particle, period.