# いろいろな便利な - In some case, two na-adjectives linked not using で?

Tags: grammar, particles, na-adjectives

With my Japanese teacher, we study some text about Doraemon.

> 未来{みらい}の**いろいろな便利{べんり}な**「ひみつ道具{どうぐ}」をポケットの中に持っている」

I was thinking **いろいろな便利{べんり}な** had to be **いろいろで便利{べんり}な**.

Comment: 多様で便利な this might be okay.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, two ordinary na-adjectives are connected with で:

> - きれいで清潔な部屋 (×きれいな清潔な部屋)
> - 親切で元気な人 (×親切な元気な人)

Nevertheless, I feel 色々な便利な道具 is far more natural than 色々で便利な道具. 便利で色々な道具 is okay but I feel this is still slightly odd.

I could not find an article which clearly explains why. But 色々 is unlike normal na-adjectives in some ways:

- It works as an adverb without に. 「いろいろ勉強した。」「いろいろ教えてください。」 [It even takes と](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6037/5010).
- Its attributive usage (i.e, modifying a following noun) is common, but its predicative usage is relatively uncommon and literary. We say 本棚に色々な本がある but 本棚にある本は色々だ sounds stiff. (If I understand correctly the English adjective *various* is not used predicatively, either. "×The books are various." I don't know if it's a coincidence.)
- It has a lexicalized [連体詞](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1016/5010) version, namely [色んな](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%89%B2%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA), which is frozen and never conjugates. (×色んだ is incorrect)

So perhaps you can think of this 色々 as a special case where 色々な is always used even when coupled with another adjective.

Comment: Do you really think きれいな清潔な部屋 and 親切な元気な人 are wrong?

Comment: 乱れた会話とか詩とかでないとは言いませんけど周辺的用法だと思うので、この段階ではとりあえず「間違い」でいいかなーと思いました。

Comment: Am I wrong to think that when i'm using な to connect the adjectives, one is modifying the next, and then when i'm using で i'm rather saying "adjective1 and adjective2"?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Do you have an example? 単純に最低な映画 is "simply the worst movie", but 単純な最低な映画 is a nonstandard/broken way to say "simple and the worst movie."

Comment: ＠naruto when I stop to think about it I feel so weird about a na adjective modifying another one like "静かな猫" a cat who is quiet. "静かな嬉しい" A happye which is quiet??? So it would make much more sense "静かで嬉しい" Queit and happy, wouldn't it? Can you think of an example where an adjective (not an adverb) modifies another adjective in english?

Answer (score -1):

When you're addressing a quality to a noun you use the adjective own particular rule:

NA adjective : place な after the adjective and then the word
I adjective: just place the word after the adjective

IE:

> 静か**な**人(shizuka na hito) - Quiet Person.
>
> 嬉しい猫（ureshii neko) - Happy Cat.

You will use で for NA adjectives when you're connecting them to another clause, but not when you're trying to modify a noun. And then use the "te form" when you're doing it with I adjectives.

> 彼女は静か**で**変だね(kanojo wa shizuka de hen da ne) - She is quiet **and** weird, right.
>
> 彼女は優し**くて**、嬉しいね(kanojo ha yasashi**kute**, ureshii ne) - She is gentle **and** happy, right.
>
> いろいろな​便利 : いろいろ is a na adjective modifying 便利, therefore it needs な to connect them, meaning Many useful...

it's tricky because japanese has a lot of adjectives that are not really adjectives in english.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But in the text we found "いろいろな便利な". It's an error ? (She took this in Genki).

Comment: @TheGrintch edited the answer, the main point is  that japanese has some adjectives that are not adjectives in english, for instance "I like you" the like in english is a verb, in japanese in a NA Adjective... and so on