# Parsing a sentence with two な-adjectives in quick succession

Tags: na-adjectives, particle-な

I'm reading a manga called Buchou wa Onee, and in the first pages, we are introduced to the main character and a few peculiar things about him as told by workmates.

https://ssl.standardbook.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/18/b3ccaa9330b8bc5567b24e4a75418939-720x1042.jpg

On the first page above, I'm met with the following line:

> カッコイイけど
> どこかヘンな
> 彼の不思議なところを
> 紹介します

`不思議な` is clearly qualifying `ところ`, but what is `ヘンな` qualifying? `彼` or `彼の不思議なところ`?

Parsing it as English, it'd become something either like

> "introduce curious sides of him who is strange in some respects"

or like

> "introduce curious sides of him which are strange in some respects",

and they both sound kind of weird to me so I can't decide which one must be correct.

There was one question that seemed related, but it didn't help me here:
[いろいろな便利な - In some case, two na-adjectives linked not using で?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/45058/%e3%81%84%e3%82%8d%e3%81%84%e3%82%8d%e3%81%aa%e4%be%bf%e5%88%a9%e3%81%aa-in-some-case-two-na-adjectives-linked-not-using-%e3%81%a7)

Answer (score 1):

The former would be correct.

If a sentence is "彼のカッコイイけどどこかヘンで不思議なところを紹介します", the latter will be fit to read.

Comment: So `ヘンな` is qualifying `彼`, making the line about the "curious sides" of the "strange him", is that it?
And, on the note of your example, does it mean that I should never expect a な-using na-adjective to qualify an already qualified noun?